# Save string pointed by pointer to array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to save string from pointer to array. But my code outputs segmentation fault. Here's my code:

```
  char timelog[maxline];
  matchescount = 0;
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    struct matches matched = check_match(line,lgd,grd);
    if (matched.status==1)
    {
      strcpy(timelog[matchescount],matched.timelog);
      matchescount++;
    }
  }
```

Here: `matched.timelog="10:24:12"` like string. And i want to save it to timelog[matchescount] . So i want this from timelog array:

```
timelog[0]="10:24:12" 

timelog[1]="10:24:13"
```

**UPDATE:**
Can i store 2d array of strings ?

> char timelog[maxline][255]

creates

```
[0][0]="1" [0][1]="0" [0][2]=":" [0][3]="2" [0][4]="4" [0][5]=":" [0][6]="1" [0][7]="2"

[1][0]="1" .......
```

right ?

Can i i store like this ?

> [0][0]="10:24:12" [0][1]="10:24:13"
>
> [1][0]="10:24:14" [1][1]="10:24:15"

Comment: `timelog` is an array of `char`s not an array of strings. Use `strncpy` to avoid buffer overruns. Tag either C or C++ (they're different languages).

Comment: Which is it, C or C++?   If it's C++, use `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: Sorry it's C. So how should i declare timelog ?

Comment: Try `char timelog[maxline][20];`. Your current `timelog` can hold 1 string not many strings.

Comment: @CoolGuy That worked ! :) You're really are Cool Guy :)

Comment: updated the answer according to your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make your array 2D. The error was because of your array is 1D so you ccan store only one string int that array.To Store multiple make the following changes.

```
 char timelog[maxline][10];
  matchescount = 0;
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    struct matches matched = check_match(line,lgd,grd);
    if (matched.status==1)
    {
      strcpy(timelog[matchescount],matched.timelog);
      matchescount++;
    }
  }
```

***UPDATE:***

```
char timelog[maxline][255]
```

creates a 2d array of char.As String is an array of chars you can store only si1D array of string in 2d array of char

```
timelog[0][0]='a';
timelog[0][1]='b';
timelog[0][2]='c';
timelog[0][3]='d';
timelog[0][4]='e';
```

this indicates you have a string "abcde" at timelog[0];

to store 2d array of strings you need a 3D char array

```
timelog[maxline][noOfStrings][maxLengthOfEachString];
```

now you can store 2D array of strings.

```
strcpy(timelog[0][0],"abcd");
strcpy(timelog[0][1],"efgh");
strcpy(timelog[1][0],"ijkl");
strcpy(timelog[1][1],"xyz");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your timelog string always look like "hh:mm:ss", you can do

```
#define MAXTIMELOG 9
#define MAXENTRIES 1000


char timelog[MAXENTRIES][MAXTIMELOG];
matchescount = 0;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    struct matches matched = check_match(line, lgd, grd);
    if (matched.status==1)
    {
        strncpy(timelog[matchescount], matched.timelog, MAXTIMELOG);
        timelog[matchescount][MAXTIMELOG-1] = 0;
        if (++matchescount == MAXENTRIES) {
            ... deal with full array ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you shouldn't copy the strings to a preallocated array. Use dynamic arrays instead:

```
size_t timelogSize = 8, matchescount = 0;
char** timelog = malloc(timelogSize*sizeof(*timelog));
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    struct matches matched = check_match(line,lgd,grd);
    if (matched.status==1) {
        if(matchescount == timelogSize) {
            timelogSize *= 2;
            timelog = realloc(timelog, timelogSize*sizeof(*timelog));
        }
        timelog[matchescount++] = strdup(matched.timelog);
    }
}
```

This has the big advantage that you can handle input strings of arbitrary size and count. By doing this everywhere you need an array, you avoid a lot of bugs that are just waiting to happen.

Comment: Instead of multiplying timelogSize with 2,shouldnt you be adding 8 to it? timelogSize += 8;

Comment: Thanks ;). It only work when matched.timelog's size is 8 right ?. What if it's size always changes ?

Comment: @varun: No, it should not be `timelogSize += 8;`. A fixed increment would give the algorithm a quadratic order, a fixed factor ensures that the algorithm stays O(N).

Comment: @akiD I have not looked at `struct matches`, so I didn't change how it's used. However, if `matched.timelog` is an array (which I suspect), I would want to replace it with a `char*` as well.

Comment: @cmaster How do i free timelog ? when i try `free(timelog)` it shows `double free or corruption (!prev)`

Comment: @akiD If you get that error, I suspect that the mistake is somewhere else (in code that I can't see). This kind of errors is easiest to debug using `valgrind`: It executes your program on an emulated CPU that adds sanity checking to all memory accesses, printing error messages on every incorrect memory access it detects. This will likely point you directly to the line where you went wrong.

Comment: @cmaster Found it,thank you, my bad :) what if timelogsize always changes ? what should i change ?

Comment: @akiD What do you mean by "`timelogsize` always changes"? `timelogsize` is simply the current size of the allocated buffer. Of course it has to change whenever more space is needed, as is done in the inner `if()` statement. Apart from controlling when to enter this inner `if()` statement, and what desired size to pass to `realloc()`, it will not be used in your code.